# Primary key and first normal form

Tags: database

Is it correct to say that: "A table with a primary key is automatically in first normal form (1NF)."?

I think the answer is affirmative since we are talking about the 1NF but I might be wrong.

Comment: Tip: This kind of question might be better asked on the sister site https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. According to 1NF definition, it's not enough. 1NF tells about attributes domain.

> First normal form (1NF) is a property of a relation in a relational database. A relation is in first normal form if and only if the domain of each attribute contains only atomic (indivisible) values, and the value of each attribute contains only a single value from that domain.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO your statement is not correct. You can have an address table with a primary key and one field for the location, which contains street, cap and city. 1NF defines, that [the domain of each attribute contains only atomic (indivisible) values](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).